# symfony 4 json_login JWT 401 Bad credentials

Tags: symfony, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

Getting `401 Bad credential` Error in `lexik jwt` token when I request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/login_check -d '{"username":"arnav@test.com","password":"123"}'
```

Firewall settings :

```
security:

    providers:
        entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt 
    firewalls:

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

And routing

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

Comment: You could just run xdebug and check the guard what's going on. Much faster and easier than asking on SO. Did you configure your webserver to forward the `Authentication` header?

Comment: yes . i am using ubantu 18.04.also run this in ARC and postman getting the same result . i am using apiplatform.

Comment: i think you forgot to add a provider to your login firewall

Comment: Issue solved my repository path in entity  is incorrect. when i corrected it its working .